# Gradle Multi Project Builds with duplicate source files

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, build.gradle

We use Gradle for our project and I am trying to setup Gradle multi-projects to make our branching process easier. For some background, our project uses an existing reference platform and adds/modifies files as required to implement our new features. In some cases where changes may have a big impact, we branch the files in question before making the changes (using Perforce).

Our project structure is as follows:

```
'root project'
    - 'subproject1'
    - 'subproject2'
    - 'subprojectN'
```

where each subproject contains branched files from root.

The `root project` has dependencies on our reference platform as such:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: "$extDir/boot", include: '*.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: "$extDir/ext", include: '*.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: "$extDir/ext/admin", include: '*.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: "$extDir/ext/client", include: '*.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: "$extDir/ext/geotools", include: '*.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: "$extDir/ext/server", include: '*.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: "$extDir/../jdk/jre/lib/", include: '*.jar')

    compile group: 'org.x', name: 'AdminControl', version: '1.9-SNAPSHOT'
    compile group: 'org.x', name: 'AutoQuery', version: '1.9-SNAPSHOT'
    ...
}
```

Here is where the issue arises, the `root project` also branches some files from our reference platform and overrides some behaviour. For example, the reference platform has a file `MRReader` which is branched into `root project` (basically contains a copy).

Now, when a `subproject` contains code using `MRReader`, it automatically references the `MRReader` found inside the reference platform (the above dependencies are under `allprojects {}`). This causes many errors such as missing methods which were added in `root project`, different behaviour, etc.

**How can we make the `subprojects {}` use the overridden files found in `root project` in favour of those found in the reference platform?**

I have tried the following:

```
subprojects {
    dependencies {
        compile rootProject
    }
}
```

to no avail. I'm thinking we have to add the root projects source directory as a source for the sub projects, but I am unsure how to do that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe try to exclude `rootProjects`'s transitive dependencies?

Comment: Is there an automatic way to do this? Or would I have to know beforehand which dependencies are duplicate and remove those one by one?

Also, I am able to get rid of the errors by simply moving up the other module's (root project) dependency up in the dependency list. If I could do the same with Gradle, this should also work. I just want it to use the root project's files over the reference platform's libraries.